# Creating ASP.NET project on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I have always been thinking that .NET framework is Windows only, and .NET Core is cross-platform (Win, Mac, Linux). And ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core is the web framework, respectively within the huge .NET or .NET Core realm. I thought the rule of thumb is that, if something does not have the "Core" suffix, it is Windows-only. However today I found I can create .NET projects using Visual Studio for Mac on my MacBook. I am really confused. Are these projects running on .NET framework (the runtime), or .NET Core? What did I miss here?

[image]

Comment: That's because the template was initially designed for Mono runtime to host ASP.NET applications as part of the open source MonoDevelop IDE. Consider the fact that Mono is not .NET Framework, your "rule of thumb" still applies. Microsoft only fully supports you if you use ASP.NET Core. If you choose the legacy "ASP.NET" templates, keep in mind that you are using Mono and issues won't be fixed. In my opinion, they should never ship those in VS for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

[.Net Framework Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/)
"The .NET Framework is a development platform for building apps for web, Windows, Windows Phone, Windows Server, and Microsoft Azure. It consists of the common language runtime (CLR) and the .NET Framework class library, which includes a broad range of functionality and support for many industry standards."

[.Net Core Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/)
".NET Core is an open-source, general-purpose development platform maintained by Microsoft and the .NET community on GitHub. It's cross-platform (supporting Windows, macOS, and Linux) and can be used to build device, cloud, and IoT applications."